# Single select Multiple TreeViewItems in one control

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my control at the moment:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="{Binding ParentName}">
    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding ChildName}" />
</TreeViewItem>
```

It's supposed to be in a `ListBox` but the catch is that I need to be able to select only the parent or the child.

It's a simple concept yet I've tried so much (wrapping in ListBoxItem. Using expanders and manually changing visibility) but nothing worked. The `ListBox` treats instances of this control as one item when it's actually two. Any ideas?

Comment: When I put that code in a TreeView, in a Grid, I can only select either. Also I just hardcoded the texts.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is TreeViewItems need to be put into a TreeView.

Comment: Well, since you edited my question, now you also have the correct answer. I can't say it's the answer to my original question.

Comment: @Ken It seemed this is what you meant. Also I think others will have this question and this answer solves their problem.

Comment: Well, I asked how to have two `ListBoxItem`s in one control. **That was the title.** This answer *has* helped me, but just for this (too localized, I guess) example. I'd change it but somehow your edit got approved so I lost control of this question, (it happened to me before on Stack Exchange).

Comment: The title said ListBoxItem, your code said TreeViewItem, so I fit the title to the code. I will edit it back they way you want it, email me: voswouter87 at google mail.